# parse table with multi pages jsoup

Tags: java, selenium, jsoup

I am trying to parse and extract data from  the table of player statistics in this [website](http://www.whoscored.com/Statistics) using jsoup and selenium in java.

But I am facing the issue while parsing the table with multiple pages.
Any suggestion how to parse all the pages in the table?

Comment: This is a dynamic page and I do not think it is possible to do such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract data from this table because the website loads data from a URL:

```
http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics?category=summary&subcategory=all&statsAccumulationType=0&isCurrent=true&playerId=&teamIds=&matchId=&stageId=&tournamentOptions=2,3,4,5,22&sortBy=Rating&sortAscending=&age=&ageComparisonType=&appearances=&appearancesComparisonType=&field=Overall&nationality=&positionOptions=&timeOfTheGameEnd=&timeOfTheGameStart=&isMinApp=true&page=&includeZeroValues=&numberOfPlayersToPick=10
```

It returns a JSON that you can parse.

Anyway you can read content from this URL using Jsoup, although it is not the right tool for this task.

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow33896871;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 33896871
 *
 */
public class App {

    private static String WHO_SCORED_URL = "http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics?category=summary&subcategory=all&statsAccumulationType=0&isCurrent=true&playerId=&teamIds=&matchId=&stageId=&tournamentOptions=2,3,4,5,22&sortBy=Rating&sortAscending=&age=&ageComparisonType=&appearances=&appearancesComparisonType=&field=Overall&nationality=&positionOptions=&timeOfTheGameEnd=&timeOfTheGameStart=&isMinApp=true&page=%d&includeZeroValues=&numberOfPlayersToPick=10";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = executeRequest(1);

        //Count the total number of pages
        Integer totalPages = jsonObject.getJSONObject("paging").getInt("totalPages");

        for(int i = 1; i < totalPages; i++){
            //It's better to sleep for some seconds to avoid 403 errors
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            jsonObject = executeRequest(i);
            handleData(jsonObject);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute the request to the server.
     * @param page The page number.
     * @return Returns the {@link JSONObject} from the body.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private static JSONObject executeRequest(Integer page) throws IOException{
        String url = String.format(WHO_SCORED_URL, page);
        Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .timeout(10 * 2000) //20 seconds timeout
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch")
                .header("Host", "www.whoscored.com")
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36")
                .header("Referer", "http://www.whoscored.com/Statistics")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .execute();
        String body = response.body();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
        return jsonObject;
    }

    /**
     * Handle data from the service.
     * @param jsonObject The {@link JSONObject} received from the service.
     */
    private static void handleData(JSONObject jsonObject){
        //My amazing business logic
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

In this example I'm also using [`org.json` `json` 20151123](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20151123) to parse the JSON response.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.davidepastore</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow33896871</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>stackoverflow33896871</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20151123</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```